# Display an ArrayList in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, arraylist, android-alertdialog

I retrieve a state list from my database. I get the list in the form of JSON.
I add all the states in an `ArrayList<String>`.
Now I want to display that complete list of states in an AlertDialog by using an Adapter.

But when I set ArrayList to an Adapter and use that Adapter in `builder.setAdapter();`, it displays the last item of my ArrayList; i.e.: only one value out of the complete ArrayList.

I don't know how to do?

below is my code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
Log.d("JSON", String.valueOf(jsonObject));
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("states");

for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)  {
    stateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONObject jobjstate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    states = jobjstate.getString("state_name");

    stateList.add(states);
    stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserRegister.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, stateList);
}

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserRegister.this);

        View customTitle = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_dialog_state, null);
        builder.setCustomTitle(customTitle);

        builder.setAdapter(stateAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                etregstate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                etregstate.setText(stateList.get(which));
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        ListView listView = alertDialog.getListView();
        listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple)));
        listView.setDividerHeight(2);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your problem is that you create a brand new adapter of one item each time through the for loop... This isn't an Android problem

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this fixes the problem

```
stateList = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)  {
    JSONObject jobjstate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    states = jobjstate.getString("state_name");
    stateList.add(states);
}

stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserRegister.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, stateList);
```

Comment: Why not? It perfectly describes the fact that you only display one element before. So, can you please be more clear as to what the problem is?

Comment: Yes you are right. I again tried the same solution you give with some changes. I make my stateAdapter as final. and create ArrayAdapter out of the loop. and It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)  {
    stateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONObject jobjstate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    states = jobjstate.getString("state_name");

    stateList.add(states);
    /* This line */
    stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserRegister.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, stateList);
}
```

You're creating a new array adapter every time you loop. Just take it out of the loop and let me know if it works! :)

Comment: It Works. I have to create stateAdapter after the loop. I understand the problem. After some changes It works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ask the above question. And After some changes I got the solution. I am posting my solution code for other's help.

Thank you.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                Log.d("JSON", String.valueOf(jsonObject));

                success = jsonObject.getInt(MateAppsConstants.TAG_SUCCESS);

                Log.d("Success", String.valueOf(success));

                if (success == 1) {
                    JSONArray stateJSON = null;
                    stateJSON = jsonObject.getJSONArray(MateAppsConstants.TAG_STATE);

                    stateList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i=0; i<stateJSON.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jobjstate = stateJSON.getJSONObject(i);
                        states = jobjstate.getString(MateAppsConstants.TAG_STATENAME);
                        Log.d("State List", states);

                        if (states != null)
                            stateList.add(states);
                    }
                } else {
                    msg = jsonObject.getString(MateAppsConstants.TAG_MESSAGE);
                    Log.d("No State Found", msg);
                }

                final ArrayAdapter<String> stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserRegister.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, stateList);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserRegister.this);
                        View customTitle = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_dialog_state, null);
                        builder.setCustomTitle(customTitle);

                        builder.setAdapter(stateAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                etregstate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                                etregstate.setText(stateList.get(which));
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                        ListView listView = alertDialog.getListView();
                        listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple)));
                        listView.setDividerHeight(2);
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                });
```